# Add new item in Django admin then redirect to another page

Tags: python, django, url

I want to  add a link from a custom template that goes into a Django admin add page:

- The model it will change is dynamic as seem in the code below, but it will have a select field, that I want to bring it already filled and disabled from further changes until saving if possible;
- After saving it goes back to the same template (passing through the view);
- Update the charts I have in the template with the new data.

I think the easiest way was to open the add page into a popup, but after the model is saved it returns to the list and doesn't close the popup, maybe there's a property to make that happen? I tried `_is_popup` but it does nothing.

Another thing I tried was messing around with the admin template called `submit_line.html` and `admin_modify.py` templatetag.

```
<a href="/admin/core/{{ indicator_key }}/add/?_is_popup=1" target="popup"
onclick="window.open('/admin/core/{{ key }}/add/?_is_popup=1',
'popup','width=600,height=800'); return false;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved after some deeper digging into the Django source code:

template.html

```
<a href="#" target="popup"
onclick="window.open('/admin/<app>/<model>/add/?_popup=1&hospital={{ hospital.id }}',
'popup','width=600,height=800'); return false;"></a>
```

In this case it will open as popup, and bring `hospital` filled with their ID automatically.

template.js

```
function dismissChangeRelatedObjectPopup(window, value, obj, new_obj) {
    window.close();
    location.reload(); 
}
function dismissDeleteRelatedObjectPopup(window, value) {
    window.close();
    location.reload(); 
}
function dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup(window, value, obj) {
    window.close();
    location.reload(); 
}
```

This javascript is added depending on your needs, it's what going to happen after saving the model on the popup. In my case I only used the add function and since I needed to reload the page to update some charts, I did that with `location.reload();`